# Gear VR Framework: Problems with cleaning (first step)

Tags: eclipse, frameworks, building, virtual-reality

I'm currently trying to set up everything to develop a Gear VR app with Eclipse in Java but I keep getting errors when I clean the Gear VR Framework project:

http://pastebin.com/yK8810bG

"Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden." simply means:
"The system cannot find the file specified."

At first Eclipse didn't recognize the directory "C:\Programme\Programmieren\AndroidNDK" (originally "Program Files" instead of "Programme" but it didn't work because of the space; has the subfolders "build", "platforms",...) as a valid folder for the NDK. According to another thread on Stackexchange, you have to create an empty file without a file extension and with the name "ndk-build" in the main folder (so "AndroidNDK"), which I did - even though there's already a file like that in the subfolder "build". That at least made Eclipse happy but now I get the above error messages.

Yes, the folders "GVRf" and "ovr_sdk_mobile" are in the same root folder and yes, I added "C:\Programme\Programmieren\AndroidNDK" to the Windows Path variable but I still get the same error messages.

I checked, the files really don't exist but I don't know, where I would even get them. I followed the steps [here](http://wiki.gearvrf.org/bin/view/GearVRfDeveloperGuide/GearVRfDevGuide200Start#BuildInstruct), including 1.b., so I should have everything necessary but apparently I don't. Plus, I double checked with [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jpDKW28_uug). I did everything the guy did - except the Git part for GVRf (I downloaded the zip) but including not copying the project into my workspace (that sadly gave me a bunch of other "cannot find..." errors) - and it worked just fine for him but not for me.

Since this doesn't work, I also can't even test the samples. :/

Any ideas where I can get the missing files or what actually could be the problem and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it:

1. There must not be any spaces in the path, so you shouldn't put the framework + NDK in a subfolder of e.g. "Program Files". Eclipse and Java usually don't care but the framework and NDK apparently do.
2. Eclipse's workspace/your project has to be on the same HDD as the framework. I've tried a couple of things but haven't gotten it to work with my usual workspace since that's on a different HDD.
3. There seemed to be a problem with the old version of the framework (April 11th to 13th), simply couldn't get it to run. It's now running fine with a newer version (April 15th) - as long as the two above points are met.